# jquery - javascript - project for fine art school

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a (french) student in a fine art school, and I make a project about memory in this project, the computer needs to forget the text that you write...

I know html and css but I just began javascript...

I need to change or to erase randomly some letters (or some words) in a text area; like you write your text normally, and when you have written 5 lines of text, the first line begins to change: some letters change (A became F or M) or some are erased...and the text means nothing. But the writers musn't see the change, it has to be very discreet (with a slow change of opacity or something like that.)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: sorry to disappoint you, but this site don't work like that. We are happy to help, but for specific questions.

Comment: Look in a bookstore for a book on Javascript that discusses changing the dom or look of the page. Then start writing your software. When you have a *specific* question, ask us here.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO! Your project sounds interesting. On SO we ask that your questions be specific. You have received a couple of down votes because your question is open ended. So to help you get started I will give you these thoughts.

1. You can't run animation effects in a textarea. You can certainly change the content, but doing so while a user is typing probably wouldn't work very well.
2. That being said, perhaps the user could type in a text area, but the actual content gets copied into a div somewhere else.
3. Animation effects need to take place on elements. To fade out individual letters you have to wrap them in a span.
4. This is actually pretty complex, so try and ask your questions piece by piece on SO. Start with your main question, and then provide a short paragraph about what you are trying to accomplish.
5. Here are some basics that will hopefully help you get started.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Btxb/

```
<div id="content">&nbsp;</div><br />
<input type="text" /><br />
Key Pressed: <div id="keycode"></div>
<button>Fade out and change a letter</button>
```

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    //in javascript you are returned a keycode as opposed to the actual 
    //letter pressed. So to work with all languages
    //I monitor keyup instead. But this means you have to clear the textarea as 
    //the user types    
    //show the keycode of the pressed key
    $('#keycode').html(e.keyCode);

    //append the typed letter to the content div
    //do you need to handle delete / cut and paste?
    $('#content').append('<span>' + $(this).val() + '</span>');

    //clear textbox
    $(this).val('');
});

$('button').click(function() {
    //find how many spans are in the content div
    var spanCount = $('#content span').length;
    //get the index of a random letter
    var randomNum = randomFromTo(0, spanCount);
    //create a random letter
    $('#content span').eq(randomNum).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        //this is a callback to the fade out animation
        //change the letters value
        $(this).html(randomLetter());
        //fade back in
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});

//generate random number between 
function randomFromTo(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

function randomLetter() {
    var letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    return letters [Math.floor(Math.random()*letters .length)];
}
```